# Is it possible to set up multiple WIFI netwoks as proxies?

Tags: proxy

For example, when i check how many WIFI networks are available on my area I find about 6 and i have access to all of them.

Is it possible to make a server or any trick to convert WIFI's to proxies and give each one a port.

(ie whenever i want to use a WIFI I only change the port)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.   Please do not add extraneous unrelated garbage to posts - A short post is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not really make a lot of sense as asked.

It is technically possible to do this, however it is an extremely advanced technique - this is something I would find challenging to pull off - and I have years of experience in this field.  **The practical answer to your question, given the level of knowledge implied in it, is no - you can't do this.**

Exploring how an expert might do this on a server (probably a Linux based machine so you can more easily access the raw components and chain the use of tools to do it) -

The key stumbling block will be identifying open networks and making connections.  The easier way would likely be to generate a list, then write some code to associate the accessible IP addresses with ports.

(A more elegant, but very hardware-dependant -but near impossible way to do this would be to simultaneously connect your router to multiple SSIDs, and then assign those SSIDs to ports - this would allow the use of more then 1 proxy at a time)

You would then need to run some kind of proxy/cache subsystem, along with policy based routing per SSID to route the requests.  You would probably need to configure multiple instances of a light-weight proxy servers for various ports, or a single proxy server and bind it to multiple ports or use IPTables to do the same.

You would likely need to monitor the ports and modify the outbound connection depending on the port - conceivably you could use a hook in the proxy server or a frankenmonster configuration of Fail2Ban to assist with this.   (If you can somehow connect to multiple networks you could likely avoid this step)

Comment: How does people create a software with multiple available residential proxies? for example vip72 proxies

Comment: They pay someone to write it? Seriously, I've no idea his $small-dodgy-random-company$ does it, and this is irrelevant to your question. I could not even download/look at there software. At a wild guess they programming a list of proxies, then configure your server to look to local host which this software then picks up and forwards to the specified proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can do this on Linux. First you need to connect to all those networks by either multiple WiFI cards and appropriate wpa_supplicant config.
When the traffic amount is limited you may either re-associate to those networks each time or build virtual TUN/TAP interface per network. You may hopp accross WiFi channels by scripting around https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airtun-ng or scapy .

Then you can use SQUID with port configuration per network possibly with additional iptables SNAT/DNAT rules.

Comment: How does people create a software with multiple available residential proxies? for example vip72 proxies